# Semi-Automatic Classification Plugin Syntax Documentation?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

I am want to integrate SCP module for DOS corrected into my script. However there appears to be no documentation of its python syntax structure available anywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's really not covered by the documentation https://fromgistors.blogspot.com/p/user-manual.html I recommend contacting the plugin developer.